# GNUwin32 make is conflicted with Git, how to avoid this situation?

Tags: git, makefile, conflict, gnuwin32

Just found an error when use GNUwin32 Make in command line:

> gnu make make: Interrupt/Exception caught

My system is Window 7. There are the Make path and the Git path in my system PATH variables.

When I remove git path from PATH variable, there's no error any more on making things.

So my question is :

Is there anyway to avoid this conflict between make and git cmds? Thanks very much~

Comment: Did you put the git path *after* or *before* the make path in your PATH?

Comment: both tried, before and after. same error.

Comment: Can you try and empty the git folder which is in your %PATH%, and add back those elements to see which one triggers the issue?

Comment: Actually I am doing some Make works, not business with git.
Some thing like "make build";

Comment: Here is my paths with git and GNU32 make:
` C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`

Comment: I understand that, but from your question, it appears that if those git executable referenced in your `%PATH%` are there, *then* your `make` commands fail. My suggestion is to empty that `git` folder, and add back those `git` executable, to see which one (by being in the `%PATH%`) will trigger the exception on your *`make`* command.

Comment: ok, let me try. Thanks~

Comment: It seems `@echo ****` in Makefile trigger the "Interrupt/Exception caught". But no any cmd named like "echo" in git bin folder. @VonC

Comment: Ok. I wasn't suggesting to remove lines in the make script. I was suggesting to remove *files* in the `git/bin` folder.

Comment: My solution is Rename the `git/bin` folder before `make build`, the return back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OP Zhaiduo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440057/zhaiduo) reports:

> It seems `@echo ****` in `Makefile` triggers the "`Interrupt/Exception caught`".
>   But no any cmd named like "`echo`" in git bin folder.

True, but there are commands which are related to managing the echo done in a shell session, like `less.exe`.

The workaround found by the OP is a bit extreme (but works):

> My solution is rename the `git/bin` folder before `make` build, the return back.